# Function with AJAX run last, how to make it run first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have one function with AJAX Call(Below Code):

```
function get_type(Name) {
  var field_name;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../home/Asset/MR/MR.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('pub').each(function() {
        if (Name == $(this).find('pro').text()) {
          $(this).find('metadata field').each(function() {
            field_name = $(this).find('name').text();

            if (field_name == "little") {
              type = "L";
            } else if (field_name == "Big") {
              type = "b";
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This code works well but the problem is it run after all the functions finished. I want to run this code first I need to get data from the XML. I need to stop the loop of `$(xml).find('pub').each(function()` this once the `Name== $(this).find('pro').text()` text is matched. Because this loop execute even I get the answers.

Calling Function codes:

```
var rd = new FileReader();
rd.onload = function(e) {
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(this.result);
  var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
  var J_Name = $xml.find('meta').text();
  get_type(J_Name);
  //check allowed child of front tag
  check_allowed_direct_child("places", "Tirunelveli,Tiruchendur,Alwar", "RULE_002", "Fail");
};
rd.readAsText(this.files[i]);
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better what your real problem is? The best way for use data that is get from an ajax call is to process this data only when you have it. You can, for example, give a **callback** function argument to the method **get_type()** and call it **on the success ajax** method with the obtained data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks to the rescue!

```js
function get_type(name, cb) {
    cb = cb || function () {};

    var field_name;
    var type;
    var types_map = {
        'little': 'L',
        'Big': 'b'
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../home/Asset/MR/MR.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml)
                .find('pub')
                .each(function () {
                    if (name == $(this).find('pro').text()) {
                        $(this)
                            .find('metadata field')
                            .each(function () {
                                field_name = $(this)
                                    .find('name')
                                    .text();

                                if (types_map.hasOwnProperty(field_name)) {
                                    type = types_map[field_name];
                                    return false; // break out of each()
                                }
                            });
                        return false; // break out of each()
                    }
                });

            cb(type); // execute provided callback
        }
    });
}

var rd = new FileReader();
rd.onload = function (e) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(this.result);
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var J_Name = $xml.find('meta').text();
    get_type(J_Name, function (type) {

        // do stuff once get_type() resolves, type being either matched type or undefined

        check_allowed_direct_child('places', 'Tirunelveli,Tiruchendur,Alwar', 'RULE_002', 'Fail');
    });
};
rd.readAsText(this.files[i]);
```

If interested, read on how to make use of Promises, to make callback code a lot more digest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

If still interested, read on how to use async / await to make Promises code a lot more digest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function